# Sigining PDF use Token RFC 3161 with itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext, bouncycastle, rfc3161

How to signed PDF with token RFC3161 use itext and BouncyCastle ?

Thanks in advance!!

```
String token = "my jeton ";
ASN1InputStream in  = new ASN1InputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(token));
ASN1Sequence seq = (ASN1Sequence)in.readObject();
```

convert token to TimeStampToken

```
TimeStampToken stp = new TimeStampToken(new ContentInfo((ASN1Sequence) seq.getObjectAt(seq.getObjectAt(0) instanceof DERTaggedObject ? 3 : 1)));
CollectionStore store =  (CollectionStore) stp.getCertificates();
Iterator itCert = store.iterator();
JcaX509CertificateConverter jcaConvertor = new JcaX509CertificateConverter();
X509Certificate[] cert = new X509Certificate[1] ;
while(itCert.hasNext()){
    X509CertificateHolder certH = (X509CertificateHolder)itCert.next();
    cert[0] = jcaConvertor.getCertificate((certH));
    System.err.println(cert);
}
```

file to sign

```
String SRC = "original.pdf";
String DEST  = "signed.pdf";
BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.addProvider(provider);
```

generate private key

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", provider.getName());
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
Base64Encoder b64 = new Base64Encoder();
generator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)pair.getPrivate();
```

itext signing method with token

```
sign(SRC, DEST, cert, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS, "", "", null, null, null, 0);
```

Comment: *"How to get the privateKey of the token for the signature?"* - How do you mean that? Private keys are private. Thus, if it is not your own, you likely won't get it.

Comment: i want to sign a pdf with a token RFC 3161 using itext.

Comment: Do you want to sign the PDF with an embedded time stamp token according to ISO 32000-1? Or do you want to add a document time stamp to the PDF according to PAdES-4?

Comment: It is according to the standard PAdES

Comment: You have already chosen the time stamp authority from which you want to retrieve the time stamps?

Comment: Yes, I have TSA that sends me a token that I converted to TimeStampToken, as the code above. My TSA does not use the rfc 3161 interface but the token is generated according to RFC 3161

Comment: I'm going to ask again mkl question since your answer points me to think you haven't completelly understood the question. Do you want to add a timestamp to a single signature or do you want to add a timestamp to the full PDF document ?

Comment: I want to add the token to PDF document